# Coding a categorical variable: 0-1 or multiple subcategories?

Tags: r, categorical-data, correspondence-analysis

I'm working with R and want to run a correspondance analysis on a dataset containing, among the others, the following factors:

**city district:  27 levels, each corresponding to a given district**

objective 1, objective 2, ... - factors with two levels (yes/no) corresponding to whether or not a person has chosen a given objective as important to him.

The question is: Does it matter if I transform the single variable *city district* into 27 binary variables? Would it impact the outcome of a correspondence analysis, including how good the data variance is described by each of the principal components?

Comment: You may want to take a look at this article: https://www.utdallas.edu/~herve/Abdi-MCA2007-pretty.pdf. R implementations of the MCA will transform themselves the factors into matrices of zeros and ones.

Comment: Thatk you for your comment! I'll take a look.